# Detect if -vf is supported (or not) in FFMPEG

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

According to the [FFMPEG docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC6), the old cropping and padding syntax is no longer supported:

> -croptop size
>   -cropbottom size
>   -cropleft size
>   -cropright size
>
> **All the crop options have been removed. Use -vf crop=width:height:x:y
>   instead.**
>
> -padtop size
>   -padbottom size
>   -padleft size
>   -padright size
>   -padcolor hex_color
>
> **All the pad options have been removed. Use -vf
>   pad=width:height:x:y:color instead.**

I'm coding a simple wrapper around FFMPEG and I would like to know if there is any straightfoward way to detect if I should use the new `-vf` syntax or not.

I've installed the latest ffmpeg package (version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1) via aptitude but it still doesn't seem to support the new syntax, so I've no idea what to look for... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be sufficient, but I don't know for sure. With ffmpeg 0.6.1, I get

```
$ ffmpeg -h 2>&1 | grep crop
-croptop size       set top crop band size (in pixels)
-cropbottom size    set bottom crop band size (in pixels)
-cropleft size      set left crop band size (in pixels)
-cropright size     set right crop band size (in pixels)
```

With ffmpeg git-8cf9a09, I get

```
$ ffmpeg -h 2>&1 | grep crop
-croptop size       Removed, use the crop filter instead
-cropbottom size    Removed, use the crop filter instead
-cropleft size      Removed, use the crop filter instead
-cropright size     Removed, use the crop filter instead
```

You may be best served to ask on [the ffmpeg-user mailing list](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user/).